# Unable to create new virtual directory in SSRS report manager

Tags: reporting-services, report, virtual-directory

Trying to change URLs

from:

```
    http://blah/ReportServer
```

to:

```
    http://blah/ReportServer/Foo
```

Error:
Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: The virtual directory specified is not valid. Make sure the specified name is not too long and doesn't contain illegal characters. (example: ;)

---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004020D): Cannot modify or delete an object that was not added using the COM+ Admin SDK (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004020D)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.ThrowOnError(ManagementBaseObject mo)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.SetVirtualDirectory(String application, String virtualDirectory)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.SetVirtualDirectory(UrlApplication app, String virtualDirectory)

Changing to:

```
    http://blah/ReportServer_Foo
```

works just fine.  Not sure what's going on.  Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its following the convention of SERVERNAME_INSTANCENAME used commonly with integrated authentication for example.